# Spring boot web services with actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws, spring-boot-actuator

I checked few other similar questions, but didn't found solution.

So I have spring boot project with web services configured:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

@Autowired
private Bus bus;

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new ServiceImpl());
    endpoint.publish("/ws");
    return endpoint;
}
}
```

ServiceImpl, like:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(serviceName = "ServiceImpl", portName = "ServiceImplPort", targetNamespace = "http://serivce.com/", endpointInterface = "pac.service...")
public class ServiceImpl...
```

service is working fine.

My POM for that implementation looks like:

```
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
   ...
```

MainClass:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @EnableScheduling
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan("com.package")
 public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
} }
```

So far, everything is working fine- WS is reachable, but If I add to POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

application start, I can see in logs:

EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/info

EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/health
etc.

and also:

ServerImpl: Setting the server's publish address to be /ws

so it's starting without any error and it looks like actuator should work, but when I tried invoke actuator endpoints I get 404 error.

when I invoke: localhost:8081/info

i get:
         
            No service was found.

I tried use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but then WS was unreachable (as well as actuator endpoints)

any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you using `@EnableWebMvc`? That disables Boot's auto-configuration of Spring MVC so that you can take complete control of its configuration. I can't see any sign of you configuring it yourself though.

Comment: I deleted @EnableWebMvc. Still when I invoke /info etc. I get:  ServletController: Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8081/info's Observer

Comment: It's hard to tell what else is wrong from the snippets of code and configuration that you've shared. A complete example, shared in a GitHub repository for example, would make it easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've mapped Spring Boot's dispatcher servlet to `/` and CXF's servlet to `/*`. This is shown in your application's log output:

```
2016-09-18 19:51:20.538  INFO 31932 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-18 19:51:20.540  INFO 31932 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/*]
```

These mappings clash and the CXF servlet wins. This means that it'll handle every request that's made to your application. This prevents Spring Boot's actuator from handling the request to `/info` for example.

You can fix the problem by moving CXF to another path by configuring `cxf.path` in `application.properties`:

```
cxf.path=/cxf
```

This will then change the mapping of its servlet accordingly:

```
2016-09-18 19:52:35.203  INFO 32213 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-09-18 19:52:35.205  INFO 32213 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/cxf/*]
```

You can now access the actuator's `/info` endpoint:

```
curl localhost:8080/info -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 18:57:08 GMT

{}
```

And the WSDL of your CXF-based service:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/cxf/ws/Hello?WSDL -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 2286
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2016 18:59:17 GMT

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://service.ws.sample/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="HelloService" targetNamespace="http://service.ws.sample/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://service.ws.sample/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://service.ws.sample/" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="sayHello" type="tns:sayHello"/>

  <xs:element name="sayHelloResponse" type="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="sayHello">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="myname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="sayHelloResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHello">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHello" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="Hello">
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHello" name="sayHello">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloResponse" name="sayHelloResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="HelloServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:Hello">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:SayHello" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="sayHello">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="sayHelloResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HelloService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/cxf/ws/Hello"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: @Andy, can you please advise how to map multiple servlet mappings for single cxf servlet? E.g. cxf.path=/cxf, /api, /health

Comment: @stinger You might be able to do it by providing a `ServletRegistrationBean` for the CXF servlet, but that will depend on how CXF's Spring Boot integration has been implemented.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thanks this is working for my issue. Can you please advise on how we can avoid the /cxf in the base path which has been mentioned in your example for getting WSDL?

http://localhost:8080/cxf/ws/Hello?WSDL

Answer (score -1):

According to [Spring Boot documentation "Customizing endpoints"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-endpoints)

> By default, all endpoints except for `shutdown` are enabled. If you
>   prefer to specifically “opt-in” endpoint enablement you can use the
>   `endpoints.enabled` property. For example, the following will disable
>   all endpoints except for info:

But to be sure, you should add this in your `application.properties` so you can use `info` endpoint :

```
endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.info.enabled=true
```

Comment: still same issue. in log file I get: ServletController: Can't find the the request for http://localhost:8081/info's Observer

Comment: BTW. I have already configured actuator in few project, but this is a different case because of using webservices instead of REST.

Comment: Setting properties to have the values that they already have by default won't make any difference